# Is it possible to create a formula for my problem?

Tags: algorithms, arithmetic

I have a business which sells steel. We order the steel at set parent lengths (7500 in the below example) and are then sent a list of measurements from our customers.

So, we need to work out the amount of steel to order at 7500mm per piece to buy, in order to fulfil an order with the absolute minimum amount of wastage which we're trying to do manually.

Customer measurements will always be sorted from biggest to smallest, the formula somehow needs to identify a combination of numbers which when added together, gets as close as possible to the parent length and do this as many times as needed so that we know how many pieces to buy.

The target here is to minimise wastage. Open to suggestions! :)

[image]

Comment: This question currently is under review for being missing context.  But the question is _only_ context!  It has little-to-no mathematical content b/c the OP doesn't know the terms to describe their problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem is called “[bin packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem)”.  It's usually phrased in terms of putting items of different sizes into fixed-size bins, using as few bins as possible.  In your version, the “items” are the required lengths, and the “bins” are the parent pieces; you're trying to use as few parent pieces as possible.

To achieve the *absolute minimum* amount of wastage as you requested is quite difficult.  No method is known that is substantially better than trying all possible ways of assigning orders to parent pieces and looking for the assignment that uses the minimum number of parents.  A skilled computer programmer would have no trouble constructing a computer program that would do this for you: you would put in the customer orders, and it would tell you the exact minimum number of parents required and how to cut them up.  The program would not be very efficient, and if there were many customer orders it would take an impractically long time to run.  But if you don't have too many orders at once, it might be useful.  (How many is “too many” depends on how well the program is written and what kind of computer you run it on.)

But there are methods that are easy to apply and produce good results in all cases if you are willing to tolerate the possibility that the solution uses a little more than the minimum number of parents.  For example the [first-fit-decreasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-fit-decreasing_bin_packing) method says:

1. Sort the customer orders by size, with the largest first, as you have
2. Go through the orders starting with the largest
3. Assign the order to the first parent that has enough material left to fill the order, if there is one
4. Otherwise, allocate a new parent and assign the order to the new parent

This is quick and easy, often uses the minimum number of parents, and in cases where it doesn't, it absolutely certain to never exceed the minimum number by more than 22%.  For example, if 40 parents is the actual minimum, the first-fit-decreasing method is guaranteed to find a way to fill the orders with no more than 49 parents, and in practice it will usually do better than this.  For the incomplete set of orders you showed I think it does actually produce the optimal result of 6 parents, but that is an unusually easy example because each order is close to half the size of the parent. (I suppose that there smaller orders that you didn't show.)

If you have a large number of orders, you may do better to use [the modified method described on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-fit-decreasing_bin_packing#Modified_first-fit-decreasing) which never uses more than about 18% more parents than the minimum.

If you're looking for someone to implement this in a spreadsheet for you to use, this isn't the right web site.  You need to contact a computer consultant who specializes in such work.